# Signature issues in Numba

Tags: python, numba

I am very new to Numba, here is my code with issues:

```
@nb.njit('(float64[:,::1], float64[:,::1], float64[::1])', parallel=True)
def jacobian_matrix(a, b, z):
    n, m = a.shape
    assert n == m and z.shape == (1,m)
    jacob = np.empty((n, n))

    for i in nb.prange(n):
        jacob[i,:] = a[i,:] - b[i,:] + z 
    
    return np.mean(jacob,axis=0)
```

I have simplified this question, under the easiest scenario the input `a` and `b` are 2 by 2 matrices, `z` is a 1 by 2 scalar. This piece of code is fine when the signature gets deleted.

However, Python keeps warning me the signature issue

```
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[34], line 2
      1 @nb.njit('(float64[:,::1], float64[:,::1], float64[::1])', parallel=True)
----> 2 def jacobian_matrix(a, b, z):
      3     eps = 0.05
      4     n, m = a.shape

File d:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\decorators.py:219, in _jit.<locals>.wrapper(func)
    217     with typeinfer.register_dispatcher(disp):
    218         for sig in sigs:
--> 219             disp.compile(sig)
    220         disp.disable_compile()
    221 return disp

File d:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py:965, in Dispatcher.compile(self, sig)
    963 with ev.trigger_event("numba:compile", data=ev_details):
    964     try:
--> 965         cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)
    966     except errors.ForceLiteralArg as e:
    967         def folded(args, kws):

File d:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py:129, in _FunctionCompiler.compile(self, args, return_type)
    127     return retval
    128 else:
...
    <source elided>
    
    return np.mean(jacob,axis=0)
    ^
```

how should I correct it?

Comment: what is the error ? paste it in the question, most likely input isn't what you expected it to be.

Comment: With Numba, providing the input with a complete example (eg. providing random input) is critical due to the strong typing. Besides, creating temporary array in a parallel loop is generally very inefficient since Numba allocations do not scale. I expect your code to spent most of its time allocating/filling temporary arrays and thread to wait each other rather than actually computing something. Please consider using basic loops. By the way, note that there is no such thing as a scalar type in Numba : `int64` and `float64` are not fully compatible.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed and Jerome, question has been reformulated into a simple matrices and vector input, and the signature has been modified according to these inputs. Still don't know what is the problem.

Comment: I think there are two main issues: 1) The command `assert z.shape == (1,m)`  is not coherent with the specified signature (`float64[::1]`). It should be `float64[:,::1]` instead (assuming c-contiguity). 2) Numba [does not support yet](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/numpysupported.html#calculation) `np.mean` with additional arguments (`axis=0` in this case). This may be the main issue during compilation.

Comment: As a sidenote, in the case you wanted to do it, the signature of the returned variable can also be specified -> in this case I think it would be `'float64[::1](float64[:,::1], float64[:,::1], float64[:,::1])'`, .i.e. it precedes the signatures enclosed by the parenthesis.